# Pause other media apps

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

When I start my MediaPlayer, other apps that are playing audio don't stop. Same when using MediaRecorder.

I managed to use `AudioManager` to have some functionality, but much of that class is either deprecated, or for high APIs.

For example, I can register a callback, but I can't unregister it cause the `abandonAudioFocus()` is deprecated.

Looking at sources, it tells me to use a `MediaSession`, but that's too complicated for my simple goal of playing a simple recorded audio, I don't want to use all the functionality of every single Android platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `AudioManager`

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

// Request audio focus for playback
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener,
// Use the music stream.
AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
// Request permanent focus.
AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);


if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
// other app had stopped playing song now , so u can do u stuff now .
}
```

> Audio focus is assigned in turn to each application that requests it.
>   This means that if another application requests audio focus, your
>   application will lose it. You will be notifi ed of the loss of audio
>   focus through the onAudioFocusChange handler of the Audio Focus Change
>   Listener you registered when requesting the audio focus

```
 private OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener =
          new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
                  public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                             AudioManager am =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    switch (focusChange) {

                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) :
                           // Lower the volume while ducking.
                           mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
                           break;
                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) :
                           pause();
                           break;

                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) :
                           stop();
                           ComponentName component =new ComponentName(AudioPlayerActivity.this,MediaControlReceiver.class);
                           am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(component);
                           break;

                           case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) :
                           // Return the volume to normal and resume if paused.
                           mediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                           mediaPlayer.start();
                           break;
                           default: break;
}
}
};
```

Comment: yes, but `requestAudioFocus()` is deprecated. Which probably means something else should be used.

Comment: If you press CTRL+left click on a method, you find the method declaration. That is where a method is created with its contents and javadoc. Javadoc for deprecated methods often include a @deprecated annotation where it mentions the new API and when it was deprecated.

Comment: It does, but the new API is very new, SDK 26. That's not backward compatible.